# REFACTOR: Clean dao code for a query with multiple optional params

Tags: java, sql, refactoring

Is there a possiblity to clean up such a dao method?
I don't like the 2 if's for each param, but there isn't something like "query.setSql()" so i could update the sql after adding the params and building the sql.

```
public List<OriginLabel> findByCriteria(Link1 l1, Link2 l2, String att) {
    String sql = "FROM MyEntity e WHERE 1=1";
    if(l1 != null){
        sql += " AND e.link1 = :l1 ";
    }
    if(l2 != null){
        sql += " AND e.link2 = :l2 ";
    }
    if(att != null){
        sql += " AND e.attribute = :att ";
    }
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
    if(l1 != null){
        query.setParameter("l1", l1);
    }
    if(l2 != null){
        query.setParameter("l2", l2);
    }
    if(att != null){
        query.setParameter("att", att);
    }
    return (List<MyEntity>)query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I store the parameters in a hashmap in the first if:

```
public List<OriginLabel> findByCriteria(Link1 l1, Link2 l2, String att) {
    String sql = "FROM MyEntity e WHERE 1=1";
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
    if(l1 != null){
        sql += " AND e.link1 = :l1 ";
        parameters.put("l1", l1);
    }
    if(l2 != null){
        sql += " AND e.link2 = :l2 ";
        parameters.put("l2", l2);
    }
    if(att != null){
        sql += " AND e.attribute = :att ";
        parameters.put("att", l1);
    }
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
    SQLUtility.setParameters(query, parameters);
```

`SQLUtility.setParameters` (easy to implement, write it yourself) loops over the `HashMap` keys and sets the parameters on the `query`.

Comment: Thx, seams pretty strait forward.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [visitor design pattrn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

You can create visitor that visits each of your parameter (which become visitable) and while doing so adds condition to your query string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe QueryDSL http://www.querydsl.com/ is something you can use to improve your SQL-related code?

When using QueryDSL your statements would be built using only one if per parameter (and your statements will be build statically typed without any string acrobatics) :

```
public List<OriginLabel> findByCriteria(Link1 l1, Link2 l2, String att) {
    QOriginLabel e = QOriginLabel.originLabel;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em).from(e);
    if (l1 != null) {
        query.where(e.link1.eq(l1)); 
    }
    if (l2 != null) {
        query.where(e.link2.eq(l2));
    }
    if (att != null) {
        query.where(e.attribute.eq(att));
    } 
    return query.list(e);
}
```

Comment: I don't like to introduce a new framework, just for such a tiny cleanup. But still good to know, it may help if i need to create more complex dynamic querys.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, I like to code it like this:

```
public List<OriginLabel> findByCriteria(Link1 l1, Link2 l2, String att) { 
    String sql = "FROM MyEntity e " +
            "   WHERE e.link1 = isnull(:l1, e.link1) " +
            "       AND e.link2 = isnull(:l2, e.link2)" +
            "       AND e.attribute = isnull(:att, e.attribute)"; 
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql); 
    query.setParameter("l1", l1); 
    query.setParameter("l2", l2); 
    query.setParameter("att", att); 
    return (List<MyEntity>)query.getResultList(); 
}
```

Comment: Would be a way, but only as long as the condition is (x!=null).

Comment: No, I do not agree. (Or I don't understand what you mean). If for example the value for l1 is null, the whereclause becomes 'where e.link1 = isnull(null, e.link1)' which evaluates as 'e.link1 = e.link1) which is always true. If l1 is not null, it evaluates to 'where e.link1 = :l1'.